# how can i debug in online judge when the input is huge?

Tags: java, debugging, testing

Today i have spent several hour on debug a program in online judge--

the problem:

Given a 2D binary matrix filled with 0's and 1's, find the largest rectangle containing only 1's and return its area.

For example, given the following matrix:

```
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0
```

[LeetCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki1UT.jpg)

my code is:
it pass the 60/66 test case, I don't know where the mistake is.I hope you can give me a good answer about my mistake and how i debug when the input is huge.

```
public class Solution {
    public int maximalRectangle(char[][] matrix) {
        if(matrix==null||matrix.length==0) return 0;
        short[][] smatrix=new short[matrix.length+1][];
        smatrix[matrix.length]=new short[matrix[0].length];
        for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
            smatrix[i]=new short[matrix[i].length];
            for(int j=0;j<matrix[i].length;j++)
                smatrix[i][j]=(short) (matrix[i][j]-'0');
        }
        for(int j=0;j<matrix[0].length;j++)
            smatrix[matrix.length][j]=0;

        //travel ever row 
        int max=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<smatrix.length;i++){
            count(smatrix[i]);
            for(int j=0;j<smatrix[i].length;j++)
                max=smatrix[i][j]>max?smatrix[i][j]:max;
        }
        if(smatrix.length==1) return max;


        //travel every row and each row to the tail-1
       for(int i=0;i<smatrix.length-1;i++){
            andTwoRows(smatrix[i],smatrix[i+1]);
            for(int j=i+1;j<smatrix.length;j++){
                max=andTwoRows(max,j-i,smatrix[i],smatrix[j]);
                if(!haveOne(smatrix[i])) break;
            }
       }
       return max;
    }
    private void andTwoRows(short[] head,short[] cur){
        short[] onehead=new short[head.length];
        short[] onecur=new short[cur.length];
        for(int i=0;i<head.length;i++){
            if(head[i]>0)
                for(int j=0;j<head[i];j++) onehead[i+j]=1;
            if(cur[i]>0)
                for(int j=0;j<cur[i];j++) onecur[i+j]=1;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<head.length;i++)
            head[i]=(short) (onehead[i]&onecur[i]);
        count(head);
    }

    private void count(short[] rows){
        for(int i=0,k=-1;i<rows.length;i++){
            if(rows[i]==0) k=-1;
            if(k<0&&rows[i]==1) {k=i;continue;}
            if(k>=0) {rows[k]+=rows[i];rows[i]=0;}
        }
    }
    private int andTwoRows(int max,int h,short[] head,short[] cur){
        short[] res=new short[head.length];
        System.arraycopy(head,0,res,0,head.length);
        andTwoRows(res,cur);

        for(int i=0;i<head.length;i++){
            if(res[i]<head[i]){
                max=h*head[i]>max?h*head[i]:max;
                head[i]=res[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    private boolean haveOne(short[] row){
        for(short tmp:row)
            if(tmp>0) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

the test case ：

```
["1111111111111101001111111100111011111111",
 "1111011011111111101101111101111111111111",
 "0111101011111101101101101111111111111111",
 "0101101011111111111101111111010110111111",
 "1111111111110111110110010111111111111111",
 "1111111110110101111111111101011111101111",
 "0110110101110011111111111111110111110101",
 "0111111111111100111111100110011011010101",
 "1111011110111111111011011011110101101011",
 "1111111110111111111101101101110111101111",
 "1110110011111111111100111111111111111111",
 "1011111110111101111001110111111111111111",
 "0110111111111111101111110111011111011111",
 "1111111111111111011111111111110111111011",
 "1111100111111110101100111111111111101111",
 "1111101111111110111111011111111111011111",
 "1111101111111111111111011001111110011111",
 "1111110111111111011111111111110111110111",
 "1011111111111111010111110010111110111111",
 "1111110011111111111110111111111111111011",
 "1111111111111111110111011111011111011011",
 "1100011011111111111111011111011111111111",
 "1111101011111111111101100101110011111111",
 "1110010111111111111011011110111101111101",
 "1111111111111101101111111111101111111111",
 "1111111011111101111011111111111110111111",
 "1110011111111110111011111111110111110111",
 "1111111111111100111111010111111111110111",
 "1111111111111111111111000111111111011101",
 "1111110111111111111111111101100111011011",
 "1111011011111101101101111110111111101111",
 "1111111111011111111111111111111111111111",
 "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111",
 "1100011111111110111111111111101111111011",
 "1111101111111101111010111111111111111111",
 "0111111111110011111111110101011011111111",
 "1011011111101111111111101111111111110011",
 "1010111111111111111111111111111110011111",
 "0111101111011111111111111111110111111111",
 "0111111011111111011101111011101111111111",
 "0111111111110101111011111101011001111011",
 "1111111111111011110111111101111111101110",
 "1111101111111100111111111110111111001111",
 "1101101111110101111101111111100111010100",
 "0110111111100111110010111110111011011101"]
```

my output: 96
expected: 114

[test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfVEx.jpg)

since the test case input is huge. how should i do when i want to debug.

Comment: When you know the sample input and the expected output, can’t you do the debugging locally?

Comment: 114, that sounds like a 6 by 19 rectangle, doesn’t it? Start by finding it in the input matrix so you know where your program is supposed to detect and record it.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you very much. when the input is small i can debug well since I know every variable what they should be. But when the input is huge I can't clearly know these variables since Huge amount of computation.

Comment: In the debuggers I know you can set conditional breakpoints: breakpoints where the program only stops if a certain condition is met. Say your maximal rectangle begins in row 12, inside your for loop set a conditional breakpoint with the condition `i == 12`. So when your debugger stops there, you already know you’re where the interesting part is supposed to happen. If this gets you started, you will probably have to elaborate yourself.

Comment: The other option: Find a smaller/simpler input where your program also fails to find the biggest rectangle by area. Then debug with that input. I would expect such a smaller example to exist.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks. thought I can't find error in my code, I change other algorithm and use submit it and be accepted.